# Styled components nesting styles or not?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

What would be a better approach for bigger scalable applications when using Styled Components? make separate variables for each html tag, or just nest the css inside the variable?

e.g.: I have the following simple structure:

```
ul {
  li {
    a {

    }
  }
}

const list = styled.ul`
   padding: 0;
   li {
    padding: 10px 0;
      a {
        color: black;
      }
   }
`
```

OR

```
 const list = styled.ul`
       padding: 0;
    `

const listLi = styled.li`
       padding: 10px;
    `

const listA = styled.a`
       color: #333;
    `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate as little as you can and combine many times.
It will make you easy to reuse components in your project.
[image]